# How to tell how much swap a Windows process actually uses?

Tags: virtualbox, performance, swap

In Windows 8.1 x64, I'm running a VBox machine that is configued to use 5200MB RAM. The host OS has 16GB of RAM, however often the other open programs add up and fill up the memory. My theory is that it slows down the VM, because VirtualBox allocates only virtual memory, and thus doesn't guarantee that the RAM that VM uses will actually be RAM in host OS - thus slowing down the VM incredibly.

Is there any way to measure how much of the process memory is in RAM, and how much of it is swapped away? (I seem to remember that in Windows 7, Virtualbox allocated "Private Bytes", so it was easier to see if the size is as expected.)

Also, is there any way to see how much swapfile reading is Windows doing? (Besides staring at the HDD LED.) I think this doesn't show in I/O graphs of Process Explorer.

[image: VirtualBox process information]

[image: VMMap information about the process]

[image: RAMMap information about the whole system]

Comment: VirtualBox doesn't just use virtual machine.  [VMMap](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533) will do what you want though.

Comment: @Ramhound, by "doesn't use virtual machine", you mean "doesn't use virtual memory"? If yes, then why does the Virtual memory say explicitly that the virtual size is 5.5GB? Because I can clearly see that the virtual machine runs, and consumes that 5.5GB of memory. Thank you for the VMMap recommendation though! I'm sad I've overlooked the tool until now.

Comment: Has to do with hardware virtualization.

Comment: Does that mean that Windows absolutely has no way to start putting that memory into swap file? (I would test it, but I'm not near that computer now.)

Comment: The host OS would page the required memory for VirtualBox.  If I am not mistaken the primary use of virtual memory by a program like VirtualBox would be to handle the virtual HDD, not the actual applications, but as I type this my own argument breaks down for a variety of reasons.  I still maintain VirtualBox itself would use your actual physical memory though, so your theory of it using virtual memory, still has holes in it.

Comment: Thanks. I will test it tomorrow and report back. On my Win7 machine, the VBox process has ~140MB private bytes, ~120MB WS, ~250MB virtual size (in Process Explorer). There's ~7GB of Driver Locked memory in RAMMap. VMMap shows it as Private Data / Locked WS. (This will take a while to wrap my head around fully.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31085/discussion-between-analytik-and-ramhound).